# How to fix "InvalidOperationException: PixelShader must be set on ShaderEffect" VS2017 error?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2017

I am getting this error message on VS2017 designer view of my WPF (.NET 4.5) application. I searched about it but couldn't find a solution. Did someone come across this error? If so, could you share the the details on fixing it?

> InvalidOperationException: PixelShader must be set on ShaderEffect.

Comment: Detailed error here https://pastebin.com/JkDx9mAx

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Only some of the folks on my team are getting this error when rendering the design view.

Comment: Unfortunately no

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had accidentally disabled “Project Code”. Re-enabling it fixed the problem.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/designers/debugging-or-disabling-project-code-in-xaml-designer?view=vs-2019

[image: Icon furthest to the right “Enable Project Code”]

Answer (score 0):

when I set the build setting to X64 I can not see the Design. but when I set the build setting to "AnyCPU" I can see the design page.
I have not resolve it.